# ¿Por qué no funciona con numeros pequeños?

Tags: c

Funciona a partir de 11, pero de 10 para abajo no sirve, por qué?
(Crea un vector con sólo números primos y los imprime en una matriz cuadrada tamaño n):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x,count=0;
    printf("Cuantos numeros se van a introducir: ");
    scanf("%i",&x);
    int matriz[x][x],vector1[x],vector0[x],i=0,j,k,l;
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        for(k=2;k<1000;k++){
            count=0;
            for(l=1;l<1000;l++){
                if(k%l==0){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(count==2){
                vector0[i]=k;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        vector1[i]=vector0[i];
    }
    int vec=0,tam,num;
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        num=i*i;
        if(num<=x){
            tam=i;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
        for(j=0;j<tam;j++){
            matriz[i][j]=vector1[vec];
            vec++;
        }
    }
    printf("Vector original: ");
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        printf("%i, ",vector1[i]);
    }
    printf("\nMatriz de numeros primos:\n");
    for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
        for(j=0;j<tam;j++){
            printf("%4i, ",matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola, espero estés bien. Te doy la bienvenida a la comunidad y te invito a leer: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, por otra parte; especifica si se muestra algún error o cual es el comportamiento al introducir los valores por debajo de 10. Saludos!

Answer (score 3):

Para empezar haces uso de VLA (Variable Length Array) que es una característica que no está soportada por el estándar desde C99 (que data de 1999). Si te compila es porque tu compilador (o alguna extensión del mismo) lo admite... pero ese código no tiene por qué compilar en otros entornos, estás avisado.

¿Y qué es un VLA exactamente?

Un VLA es un array cuyo tamaño se determina en tiempo de ejecución (no tiene un tamaño fijo). En tu caso `matriz`, `vector1` y `vector0` son VLA porque su tamaño se basa en el valor de `x` que es una variable:

```
printf("Cuantos numeros se van a introducir: ");
scanf("%i",&x);
int matriz[x][x],vector1[x],vector0[x]
//  ^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^
//    VLA          VLA        VLA
```

Por otro lado piensa que los VLA se almacenan en la pila del programa... que es relativamente pequeña. Una matriz de `x*x` elementos puede desbordarla con cierta facilidad (piensa que para `x=2` se consumen 32 bytes pero para `x=20`, 3200... el consumo aumenta de forma exponencial)

Mi consejo es que evites esta práctica (aunque te compile) y tires de memoria dinámica que sirve precisamente para cubrir estos casos. Aun así y dado que te compila, este no es el origen de tu problema, pero te lo comento para que lo sepas.

Por otro lado, lo extraño es que te llegue a funcionar cuando introduces 11, 12, ...

```
for(i=0;i<x;i++){ // <<---
    for(k=2;k<1000;k++){
        count=0;
        for(l=1;l<1000;l++){
            if(k%l==0){
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count==2){
            vector0[i]=k;
            i++; // <<---
        }
    }
}
```

Fíjate en las dos líneas señaladas y verás que ambas incrementan `i`. La primera en sí no es problemática ya que representa una iteración sobre el rango (0,x-1). Sin embargo el segundo incrementa el valor de `i` de forma descontrolada.

El segundo bucle (el bucle `k`), trabaja siempre sobre un rango fijo de elementos independientemente del tamaño asignado a `vector0`.

- ¿Cuantos primos hay menores que 1000? 168
- ¿Qué tamaño tiene `vector0` si `x==10`? 10
- ¿Qué sucede cuando guardas el primo número 11? Que empiezas a pisar memoria de otras variables?
- ¿Y con los primos sucesivos hasta el 168? lo mismo

Tu planteamiento del programa está mal. Tienes que generar, únicamente, `x` números primos. Por otro lado no hace falta que para saber si un número `n` es primo lo compares con todos los números más pequeños... basta con utilizar la lista de primos que has encontrado hasta la fecha:

```
for( int numPrimos=0, numero=2; numPrimos<x; numero++ )
{
  int primo = 1;
  for( int j = 0; j < numPrimos && primo != 0; ++j )
    primo = numero%vector0[j];

  if( primo != 0 )
  {
    vector0[numPrimos] = numero;
    numPrimos++;
  }
}
```

Con esto ya tienes `vector0` poblado con los `x` primeros números primos... ya solo te queda pasarlo a forma de matriz

Comment: Lo raro también es que ayer estuve probando el código de OP y se ejecuta si quitas los printf, el error decía "stack smashing detected", no se si se te ocurre qué es... busqué y se decía mucho que es por el buffer de printf y cómo se maneja en la consola las lecturas y escrituras pero no pude hacer que funcionara.

Comment: @zerocool es dependiente del compilador y del sistema operativo... dependiendo de qué zonas de memoria pise y lo que haya en ellas (y eso depende del compilador) tendrás un resultado u otro... si pisas memoria puede pasar cualquier cosa