# ¿Como hacer la interseccion de dos cadenas de texto?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Con La intersección me refiero a que si tengo dos oraciones me guarde las palabras y no los carácter iguales

---

```
//Programa para la interseccion de dos cadenas de texto

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

string x,y,frase;
cout<<"Ingrese los elementos de x: ";
 getline(cin,x);
cout<<"Ingrese los elementos de y: ";
 getline(cin,y); 
cout<<"Elementos de x: "<<endl;
for(int i=0; i<x.length();i++){
    cout<<x[i];
}
cout<<"\n"<<endl;
cout<<"Elementos de y: "<<endl;
for(int j=0; j<y.length();j++){
    cout<<y[j];
}
cout<<"\n"<<endl;
cout<<"Interseccion: "<<endl;
for(int i=0; i<x.length();i++){
    for(int j=0; j<y.length();j++){
        if(x[i]==y[j]){
            cout<<x[i];//Me produce error ya que cuento los caracter
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de datos de entrada y la salida que esperas con ellos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Veo que tu código requiere identificar las palabras de ambas oraciones que son iguales.Sin embargo lo que hace es identificar que letras en ambas oraciones son coincidente.

Yo lo resolví de esta manera:

- Ingresamos la oración X e Y.
- Contamos cuantas palabras hay en la oración X.
- Creamos un vector con esa dimensión.
- Introducimos las palabras de la oración X en ese vector.
- Contamos cuantas palabras hay en la oración Y.
- Creamos otro vector con esa dimensión.
- Introducimos las palabras de la oración Y en ese vector.
- Comparamos todos los elementos del VectorX con todos los del VectorY para ver que palabras son Coincidentes.

Se puede mejorar de muchas maneras, por ejemplo en vez de contar palabras y luego introducirlas, se puede crear un vector dinámico que cuente y se auto dimensione a medida que vaya detectando nuevas palabras. También se puede hacer que no discrimine las mayúsculas y minúsculas, porque solo te detecta las palabras exactas.

```
//Programa para la interseccion de dos cadenas de texto

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int contadorx, cantidadx, cantidady, contadory;
    string x,y,frase,palabrax, palabray;
    cout<<"Ingrese los elementos de x: ";
    getline(cin,x);
    cout<<"Ingrese los elementos de y: ";
    getline(cin,y); 

    cout << endl;

    /* Verificamos la cantidad de palabras en la primer oracion */
    cantidadx=0;
    contadorx=0;


    while (contadorx<x.length())
    {
        while(x[contadorx]!=' ' && contadorx<x.length()){
            contadorx++;            
        }
        contadorx++;
        cantidadx++;        
    }

    /* creamos el vector para contenerlas */

    string VectorX[cantidadx];

    cantidadx=0;
    contadorx=0;
    palabrax="";

    while (contadorx<x.length())
    {
        while(x[contadorx]!=' ' && contadorx<x.length()){
            palabrax=palabrax+x[contadorx];
            contadorx++;            
        }
        VectorX[cantidadx]=palabrax;
        contadorx++;
        cantidadx++;        
        palabrax="";
    }

    cout << "Elementos de X: " << endl;

    for (int i=0;i<cantidadx;i++){
        cout << VectorX[i] << endl;
    }

    /* Fin de insertar palabras en el vector de X */

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Elementos de Y: " << endl;
    /* Verificamos la cantidad de palabras en la segunda oracion */
    cantidady=0;
    contadory=0;        
    while (contadory<y.length())
    {
        while(y[contadory]!=' ' && contadory<y.length()){
            contadory++;            
        }
        contadory++;
        cantidady++;        
    }

    /* creamos el vector para contenerlas */

    string VectorY[cantidady];

    cantidady=0;
    contadory=0;
    palabray="";

    while (contadory<y.length())
    {
        while(y[contadory]!=' ' && contadory<y.length()){
            palabray=palabray+y[contadory];
            contadory++;            
        }
        VectorY[cantidady]=palabray;
        contadory++;
        cantidady++;        
        palabray="";
    }

    for (int i=0;i<cantidady;i++){
        cout << VectorY[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    /* Fin de insertar palabras en el vector de X */

    /*Empezamos a ver que palabras coinciden */
    for (int xx=0;xx<cantidadx;xx++){
        for (int yy=0;yy<cantidady;yy++){
            if (VectorX[xx]==VectorY[yy]){
                cout << "Coinciden: " << VectorX[xx] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muy bueno, intente hacer la Diferencia de palabras pero se me repiten por que es el caso: 
for (int xx=0;xx<cantidadx;xx++){
        for (int yy=0;yy<cantidady;yy++){
            if (VectorX[xx]!=VectorY[yy]){
                cout << "Coinciden: " << VectorX[xx] << endl;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Buenas tardes, el código compara cada elemento del primer vector con cada elemento del segundo, por lo tanto cada vez que no coincida te va aparecer el elemento. Para que te escriba una sola vez debes comparar el elemento del primer vector con todos y cada unos de los elementos del segundo y recién ahí decidir si hubo coincidencia o no.. se puede hacer con una variable tipo bandera

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de [@HernanL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/166625/463). puede que funcione, pero no es recomendable porque, entre otras cosas, usa [VLA](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/162770/463), algo que no está soportado por el estándar.

Para leer las cadenas yo apostaría, si tienes margen de maniobra, por hacer uso de la STL, que para algo está:

```
std::vector<std::string> LeerLinea()
{
  std::string linea;
  std::getline(std::cin,linea);

  std::vector<std::string> toReturn;
  std::istringstream iss(linea);
  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
            std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
            std::back_inserter(toReturn));

  return toReturn;
}
```

Lo que hace esta función es, básicamente, leer una línea de texto completa y almacenarla en `linea` para, a continuación, almacenar la cadena en un *stream* especial (`istringstream`) y no, no se puede hacer directamente.

La gracia de almacenar la línea leída en este *stream* es que nos va a permitir usar la función `copy` para iterar sobre cada palabra. `back_inserter` es una función de utilidad que, cada vez que se invoca, llama al método `push_back` de `toReturn`. En resumen... se coge cada palabra y se añade al vector `toReturn`.

Con esto ya podemos leer facilmente las dos líneas de entrada:

```
std::cout<<"Ingrese los elementos de x: ";
std::vector<std::string> x = LeerLinea();
std::cout<<"Ingrese los elementos de y: ";
std::vector<std::string> y = LeerLinea();
```

Y ya solo nos falta calcular la intersección. Casualmente, en la librería `algorithm` hay una función que calcula la intersección entre dos colecciones de elementos... fíjate tu que cosas, luego la forma más sencilla de finalizar el programa podría ser usar dicha función:

```
std::vector<std::string> interseccion;

std::set_intersection(std::begin(x),std::end(x),
                      std::begin(y),std::end(y),
                      std::back_inserter(interseccion));
```

Lo que hace `set_intersection` es rellenar el vector `interseccion`... no tiene mucho misterio. Podemos verificar que el resultado es correcto simplemente iterando sobre el vector `iteracion`:

```
std::cout << "Interseccion:\n";
for( std::string palabra : interseccion )
  std::cout << "  " << palabra << '\n';
```