# Como retornar una matriz en C?

Tags: c, funciones, matrices

Mi problema es una matriz declarada en una funcion como hago para tener los valores de la matriz en una segunda funcion que la imprima, algo como esto:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>
void main(){
int m,n;
printf("ingrese 2 numeros:");
scanf("%i %i",&m,&n);
declarar(m,n);\\RETORNAR LA MATRIZ
imprimir(matrix,m,n);\\USAR LA MATRIZ ANTERIOR
getch();
}
void declarar(int a,int b){
srand(time(NULL));
int i,j,matrix[a][b];
for(i=0;i<a;i++){
    for(j=0;j<b;j++){
        matrix[i][j]=1+rand()%7;
    }
}
}
void imprimir(int c[100][100],int a,int b){
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<a;i++){
    for(j=0;j<b;j++){
        printf("%i\t",c[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

Como retorno la matriz para usarla en la siguiente funcion?

Answer (score 2):

La matriz que has declarado es un VLA y es algo no soportado por el estándar desde C99, es decir, desde 1999.

```
int matrix[a][b]; // VLA
```

Si te compila es porque tu compilador te ofrece esa funcionalidad, pero dicha funcionalidad no tiene por qué ser portable a otros compiladores ni, por supuesto, a versiones más modernas de tu compilador. El tema del VLA se ha tratado en otras ocasiones: [enlace 1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/115649/463), [enlace2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/162770/463)

El caso es que el uso de VLA presenta algunas restricciones, como  has podido comprobar. La solución pasa por usar memoria dinámica:

```
int** declarar(int a,int b){
  srand(time(NULL));
  int i,j,**matrix;

  matriz = (int**)malloc(a*sizeof(int*));
  for(i=0;i<a;i++){
    matriz[i] = (int*)malloc(b*sizeof(int));
    for(j=0;j<b;j++){
        matrix[i][j]=1+rand()%7;
    }
  }
  return matriz;
}
```

Por supuesto, cuando la matriz no sea necesaria, tienes que acordarte de liberar la memoria:

```
for( int i=0;i<b;i++ )
   free(matriz[i];
free(matriz);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu Problema es que la matriz esta declarada dentro del **alcanze(scope)** de la funcion **declarar** por lo cual esta crea la matriz en el **pila(stack)**. al momento de retornar el stack disminuyen eliminando cualquier refencia de las variables declaradas dentro de esta funcion porque se entiende que ya no se va a utilizar.

Al momento de entrar en una funcion o dentro de un bucle o simplemente dentro de unos bracket {} el stack crece y este conserva todas las variables declaradas dentro de estos bracket, al momento de salir es stack disminuye destruyendo la referencia de cada variable declarada dentro de los bracket

```
//Global Scope
int G;

int main()
{
    //Primer Scope de la funcion main
    int A;
    printf("%p\n", &A);
    printf("%p\n", &G);

    {
        //Segundo Scope de la funcion main
        int B;
        printf("%p\n", &B);
        printf("%p\n", &A);
        printf("%p\n", &G);
    }
}

int func()
{
    //Primer Scope de la funcion func
    int A;
    printf("%p\n", &A);
    printf("%p\n", &G);
}
```

En el ejemplo siguiente te muestro que la variable B no existe fuera del segundo scope, por lo cual no se puede utilizar en el primer scope, pero la variable A fue declarada en el primer scope y como el segundo scope esta dentro del primer scope esta puede utilizar la variable A. Ahora bien ni A ni B que fueron declaradas dentro de main pueden ser utilizadas fuera de esta por que son variable locales a la funcion main. La variable A dentro de la funcion func es diferente a la variable A dentro de la funcion main porque estan en scope diferentes. Y la variable G como esta en el Scope Principal o Global puede ser utilizada dentro de cada funcion en ese archivo.

Puedes solucionar tu problema declarando int ** matrix global o dentro del scope de main.

```
//1. Glogal
int ** matrix;
void main()
{
    int m,n;
    printf("ingrese 2 numeros:");
    scanf("%i %i",&m,&n);
    declarar(m,n);\\RETORNAR LA MATRIZ
    imprimir(matrix,m,n);\\USAR LA MATRIZ ANTERIOR
    getch();
}

void declarar(int a, int b)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i,j;

    matriz = (int**)malloc(a*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0;i<a;i++){
        matriz[i] = (int*)malloc(b*sizeof(int));
        for(j=0;j<b;j++){
            matrix[i][j]=1+rand()%7;
        }
    }
}

void imprimir(int ** c,int a,int b)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<a;i++){
        for(j=0;j<b;j++){
            printf("%i\t",c[i][j]);
            free(c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        free(c[i]);
    }
} 

//2. Local a Main
void main()
{
    int m,n;
    int ** matrix;
    printf("ingrese 2 numeros:");
    scanf("%i %i",&m,&n);
    declarar(m,n, &matrix);\\RETORNAR LA MATRIZ
    imprimir(matrix,m,n);\\USAR LA MATRIZ ANTERIOR
    getch();
}

void declarar(int a, int b, int *** matrix)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i,j;

    (*matrix) = (int**)malloc(a*sizeof(int*));
    for (i=0; i<a; i++){
        (*matrix)[i] = (int*)malloc(b*sizeof(int));
        for(j=0; j<b; j++){
            (*matrix)[i][j]=1+rand()%7;
        }
    }
}

void imprimir(int ** c,int a,int b)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<a; i++){
        for(j=0; j<b; j++){
            printf("%i\t",c[i][j]);
            free(c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        free(c[i]);
    }
}
```

**la pila(Stack)** almacena las llamada y los parametro a cada funcion mientras el codigo se va ejecutando, este crece y se destruye dinamicamente y automaticamente.

el **heap** reserva memoria para las variable dinamicas que vas necesitando en la ejecucion del programa, este crece y se destruye dinamicamente pero no automaticamente. al utilizar la funcion **malloc** se reserva memoria de un tamaño especifico y al utilizar **free** se libera esta memoria.

Comment: No es para nada necesario usar variables globales en este punto