# Tengo este codigo, como debo usar el ciclo For para la Matriz?

Tags: array, c, matriz

Quiero imprimir las diagonales, en incremento y decremento si n=5 solo no se que debo tener en en cuenta para continuar, pensé en hacer un if cuando i==j entonces 1, lo que hace la diagonal principal o 2 for dentro del for principal, uno para que hiciera decremento y el otro incremento antes y después de la diagonal principal pero no se como implementarlo:

> ```
> 1 2 3 4 5
> 2 1 2 3 4
> 3 2 1 2 3
> 4 3 2 1 2
> 5 4 3 2 1
> ```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n=0;
    int count=0, count2=0;

    printf("Ingrese un numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int matriz[n][n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        count=i+1;
        
        
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j){
            
            matriz[i][j]=count;
            
        }       
        
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j){
            
            printf("%3d",matriz[i][j]);
            
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La diagonal descendente es la que tiene todos sus componentes incrementando en uno:

> ```
> [0,0] 1       2       3       4       5
>       2 [1,1] 1       2       3       4
>       3       2 [2,2] 1       2       3
>       4       3       2 [3,3] 1       2
>       5       4       3       2 [4,4] 1
> ```

En la ascendente, crecen las columnas pero decrecen desde el máximo las filas:

> ```
>       1       2       3       4 [4,0] 5
>       2       1       2 [3,1] 3       4
>       3       2 [2,2] 1       2       3
>       4 [1,3] 3       2       1       2
> [0,4] 5       4       3       2       1
> ```

Por lo tanto, basta con un bucle:

```
printf("Diagonal descendente:\n");

for (int indice = 0; indice != n; ++indice)
    printf("%3d", matriz[indice][indice]);

printf("Diagonal ascendente:\n");

for (int indice = 0; indice != n; ++indice)
    printf("%3d", matriz[indice][n - indice]);
```

### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

No puedes crear matriz n×n de tamaño estático usando una variable, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/162770/2742) para saber por qué.