# Leer una cadena con un subíndice entero

Tags: c, string, variables

Tengo un programa que lee una cadena, pero el subíndice es entero. No se que identificador de variable debo usar para leer una cadena en este tipo de situación.

```
int main()
{
    int clientes;
    scanf("%d", &clientes);

    char nom[clientes];
    double compra[clientes];

    for (int i=0; i<clientes; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("Escriba su nombre para esta compra\n");
        scanf("%x", nom[i]); //<-- tira advertencia porque está mal el identificador de variables y no sé cual poner
        printf("Indique también cual es su monto total de compra\n");
        scanf("%x", compra[i]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu idea es almacenar una colección de cadenas de caracteres, pero únicamente has reservado espacio para uno de ellos:

```
char nom[clientes];
```

Las cadenas de caracteres son arrays de caracteres, es decir, una secuencia de caracteres de tamaño indeterminado. Es por ello que necesitas un puntero para cada cadena de caracteres ... como son varias entonces necesitas un array:

```
char nom[NUMERO_DE_ARRAYS][LONGITUD_DE_CADA_ARRAY];
```

En C, obviando el uso de [VLA](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/162770/463), tendrías que tener algo tal que:

```
// Reserva de memoria
char **nom = (char**)malloc(clientes * sizeof(char*));
for( int i=0; i<clientes; i++)
{
    // Cada cadena de caracteres tendrá capacidad para 100 caracteres
    nom[i] = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char)));
}

for (int i=0; i<clientes; i++)
{
    printf("\n");
    printf("Escriba su nombre para esta compra\n");
    scanf("%s", nom[i]); // <<--- estás leyendo una cadena de caracteres
}

// ...

// Se libera la memoria
for( int i=0; i<clientes; i++)
{
    free(nom[i]);
}
free(nom);
```

Comment: ¿Y con la variable compra como hago? Tira error también

Comment: @AlejandroCaro nota que `scanf` espera recibir un puntero...

Comment: pongo compra[i] = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char)); y tira error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'double' from type 'char *'|

Comment: @AlejandroCaro a ver, no estás prestando atención a lo que estás haciendo. `compra` es una variable de tipo `double`. No es un puntero y desde luego no es de tipo `char`. Yo solo te he dicho que `scanf` necesita un puntero, no que debas cambiar el tipo de `compras`. Pista: operador `&`